# Securing Redis in docker with docker-compose

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yaml file as below and I want to make sure that port 6379 on the server is not exposed to the internet (just to the first container "web" mentioned).

If I just remove the "expose" link from the "redis:" section, will that keep my redis working internally but block it from being accessed from outside?

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        image: myimage/version1:1.4.5
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8082:3000
        container_name: web
        networks:
            - web
            - default
        expose:
            - '3000'
        labels:
            - 'traefik.docker.network=web'
            - 'traefik.enable=true'
            - 'traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:abcd.com'
            - 'traefik.basic.port=3000'
            - 'traefik.basic.protocol=http'
        depends_on:
            - redis
    redis:
      image: redis:4.0.5-alpine
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 6379:6379
      expose:
        - 6379
      command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
      hostname: redis
      networks:
        - web
      volumes:
        - redis-data:/data


networks:
    web:
        external: true

volumes:
  redis-data:
```

Answer (score 3):

[Expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose) makes the port accessible only to linked services which is what you want. You should remove the redis [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) so the port will not be bound to the host.

Comment: Following that logic, shouldn't part 8082 be publicly available also? (it's not)

Comment: @Pete you should only remove ports section from redis service and keep ports section for web. then web would be accessible from outside but redis would not be accessible from outside.